# Building react js app its frizzing with the message Creating an optimized production build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to build the project in the development mode. I'm running in the terminal the command **npm run build** but the build its frozen with the text **Creating an optimized production build...** most of the times. But sometimes its returning this error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
    50 |           <div className="mb-2">
    51 |             <TextInput
  > 52 |               register={register('first_name', {
       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 53 |                 required: {
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 54 |                   message: 'First Name its required',
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 55 |                   value: true,
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 56 |                 },
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 57 |               })}
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    58 |               placeHolder="First name"
    59 |               className="text-black border rounded border-gray-300 w-full font-normal p-3"
    60 |               error={errors.first_name?.message || ''}
```

I have never seen this error before, nor am I finding something about it in the google.
**Im using typescript, redux, redux saga and useForm for the forms in this project.**
**This is my component for the TextInput**:

```
import React, { FC, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { UseFormRegisterReturn } from 'react-hook-form';
import { classNames } from '../../../../utils/classNames';

interface ITextInput extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  register?: UseFormRegisterReturn;
  label?: string;
  classNameLabel?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  type?: string;
  placeHolder?: string;
  className: string;
  error?: string;
}

export const TextInput: FC<ITextInput> = ({
  register,
  classNameLabel,
  label,
  placeHolder,
  value,
  className,
  error,
  ...props
}) => {
  const propsAndRegister = { ...register, ...props };
  return (
    <>
      <label
        className={classNames(
          'block font-auth text-base font-normal',
          classNameLabel || '',
        )}
      >
        {label}
        <input
          data-test-id="checkbox-input"
          {...propsAndRegister}
          placeholder={placeHolder}
          value={value}
          className={classNames(
            'w-full mt-0.5 p-1.5 border text-title text-opacity-100 border-borderColor',
            className,
          )}
        />
        {error ? (
          <span
            className="block text-xs text-red-900 py-0.5"
            data-test-id={`error-${value}`}
            data-test="error-input"
          >
            {error}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <span className="block h-1 mt-1" />
        )}
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.54",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.8",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.46.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router": "^6.16.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.7",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

This is my **store file**:

```
// import sagas
import sagas from '../sagas/index';

// import reducers
import reducers from './reducers';

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

const sagaMiddleweare = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  middleware: () => [sagaMiddleweare],
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
sagaMiddleweare.run(sagas);
export default store;
```

And this is my **tsconfig.json file**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure there will be an easy answer here, [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34933) opened in Typescript repo since 2019 and still not resolved. Maybe you will find some insights in it.